# HTTPS for unlimited domains

Tags: nginx, https, lets-encrypt

I'm working in a project similar to wix.com and shopify.com:

- The companies that hire my service setup their NS records to my server
- All of their visitors need to access through https
- I'm looking for a solution that (possibly) uses letsencrypt.org in order to reduce costs
- I'm using nginx server and I'm able to configure https with one single domain

The question is:

- which approach can I use in order to not create encryption keys to each domain I host? I'm looking for a solution that scales
- Today I'm usign a single server to host all companies but this is about to change. How can I manage multiple keys accross multiple servers (considering there's no solution using single keys)?

I know the question may sounds vague, but at least point me to a starting point to investigate.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Issuing a letsencrypt certificate can be fully automated, so why don't you do that? What is the core problem with different certificates for each subdomain?

Comment: It seems that issuing certificates for each domain may not scale - where would I store all certificates? Considering I may have many servers

Comment: You need about 4kB per certificate, if you only keep the live versions (the others can be compressed and backed up if you want to keep them), and 2kB per configuration. That means that you can store the files for about 3 million server names on a 20GB disk. How many are you going to add that this won't scale?

Comment: I've got your point about cert's storage size. I thought that a few hundread domains would be a problem. But in this case I'd need to update my certificate and reload nginx (wouldn't I?) Can't I use some sort of generic cert for multiple domains instead?

Comment: Updating the certificates and reloading nginx can also be automated, see e.g. [this](https://www.nginx.com/blog/free-certificates-lets-encrypt-and-nginx/). Yes, you can get a wildcard certificate for `*.example.com`, but not with letsencrypt - so this will cost you money.